# Node.js - How do I upload an image to Backblaze b2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, multer

I am getting connect `Request failed with status code 400` from b2.uploadFIle()

Here's what I tried to do:

Step 1: Download [backblaze-b2 node.js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backblaze-b2) and [multer(to get image file in req.body)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Step 2: Set up how I'm going to call my route in POSTMAN. I have attached an IronMan.png in my request.
[image]

Step 3: Set  up my code:

```
       import B2 from "backblaze-b2";  
  export const uploadCreationImage = async (
) => {
    try {
        const b2 = new B2({
            applicationKeyId: process.env.backblazeb2ApplicationKeyId, 
            applicationKey: process.env.backblazeb2ApplicationKey, 
        });

        await b2.authorize(); // must authorize first (authorization lasts 24 hrs)
        console.log("I am here");
        let response = await b2.getBucket({
            bucketName: "bucketName",
        });

        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, "./uploads");
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, file.originalname);
            },
        });

        const multerUploader = multer({});
 upload(req, res, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                return res.sendStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_STATUS);
                // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
            } else if (err) {
                // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
                return res.sendStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_STATUS);
            }
            // console.log("joe", req.file.buffer);
            // console.log("biden", req.file);
            b2.getUploadUrl({
                bucketId: "58dd09e54842aafc7dcd0917",
                // ...common arguments (optional)
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log("getUploadUrl", response.data.uploadUrl , response.data.authorizationToken);
                
                b2.uploadFile({
                    uploadUrl: response.data.uploadUrl,
                    uploadAuthToken: response.data.authorizationToken,
                    fileName: "fileName",
                    data: req.file.buffer, // this is expecting a Buffer, not an encoded string
             
                
                    onUploadProgress: null,
                    //onUploadProgress: (event) => {} || null // progress monitoring
                    // ...common arguments (optional)
                }).then((response) => {
                    console.log('uploadFIle', response); 
                    return res.send({ path: req.file.originalname });
                } 
               
                // Everything went fine and save document in DB here.
            });
        });
```

I used multer to get the image file from the form request and then pass it to b2.uploadFile's data property as a buffer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed! all I had to do was to get rid of the optional parameters in b2.uploadFile()

```
upload(req, res, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                return res.sendStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_STATUS);
                // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
            } else if (err) {
                // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
                return res.sendStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_STATUS);
            }
          
            b2.getUploadUrl({
                bucketId: process.env.backblazeb2BucketId,
                // ...common arguments (optional)
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(
                    "getUploadUrl",
                    response.data.uploadUrl,
                    response.data.authorizationToken
                );

                b2.uploadFile({
                    uploadUrl: response.data.uploadUrl,
                    uploadAuthToken: response.data.authorizationToken,
                    fileName: "fileName",
                    // contentLength: 0, // optional data length, will default to data.byteLength or data.length if not provided
                    //mime: "", // optional mime type, will default to 'b2/x-auto' if not provided
                    data: req.file.buffer, // this is expecting a Buffer, not an encoded string
                    //hash: "sha1-hash", // optional data hash, will use sha1(data) if not provided
                    // info: {
                    //     // optional info headers, prepended with X-Bz-Info- when sent, throws error if more than 10 keys set
                    //     // valid characters should be a-z, A-Z and '-', all other characters will cause an error to be thrown
                    //     key1: "value",
                    //     key2: "value",
                    // },
                    onUploadProgress: (event) => {},
                    //onUploadProgress: (event) => {} || null // progress monitoring
                    // ...common arguments (optional)
                }).then((response) => {
                    console.log("uploadFIle", response);
                    return res.send({
                        path: req.file.originalname,
                    });
                });

                // Everything went fine and save document in DB here.
            });
        });
```